# How to run couple of roles in parallel in Ansible playbook?

Tags: parallel-processing, ansible

I need to run some roles in concurrent mode in Ansible.

I run ansible via:

```
ansible-playbook install_full.yml --tags "10_clean_up,20_pull_images,30_install_postgres_11,40_install_jboss-eap-7.0" --extra-vars "ansible_user=user ansible_password=password"
```

The playbook install_full.yml looks like:

```
- hosts: localhost

  vars_files:
    - "vars/build.yml"

  roles:
    - { role: 10_clean_up, tags: 10_clean_up }
    - { role: 20_pull_images, tags: 20_pull_images }
    - { role: 30_install_postgres_11, tags: 30_install_postgres_11 }
    - { role: 40_install_jboss-eap-7.0, tags: 40_install_jboss-eap-7.0 }
```

30 and 40 role can be run in the same time (to save some time), is it possible to run couple of roles in parallel, not like now - by order list ?

Thanks on advance!

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible at this time and many have asked for that feature. From the ansible project : https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/19083.
FYI it is possible to use async on tasks, but it is not possible to use it on roles.

Answer (score -2):

You'd need `strategy: free` for the set of roles you want to run at the same time. Check this out:

https://medium.com/@ibrahimgunduz34/parallel-playbook-execution-in-ansible-30799ccda4e0

Comment: this is incorrect, the free strategy is to tell multiple nodes that they can behave independently. Each node can go through its assigned steps and "run until the end of the play as fast as it can:" - this won't help running roles in parallel on a single node.
see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html